# VBA. Auto fit cell height not working for merged cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code to autofit a merged cell having a large value but it is not working

```
Sub test1()
    Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Value = " Testing Testing TestingTestingTesting Testing  Testing  TestingTestingTesting Testing  TestingTesting  Testing  Testing  TestingTesting  Testing Testing  Testing  TestingTesting  Testing  TestingTesting  Testing Testing  Testing  Testing  Testing  Testing  Testing TestingTestingTesting  Testing Testing Testing TestingTestingTesting Testing  Testing  TestingTestingTesting  Testing  TestingTesting Testing  Testing  TestingTesting  Testing  Testing  Testing TestingTesting  Testing  TestingTesting  Testing  Testing  Testing Testing  Testing  Testing  Testing  TestingTestingTesting  Testing Testing Testing TestingTestingTesting  Testing  Testing TestingTestingTesting  Testing  TestingTesting  Testing  Testing TestingTesting  Testing  Testing  Testing  TestingTesting  Testing TestingTesting  Testing  Testing  Testing  Testing  Testing  Testing Testing  TestingTestingTesting  Testing"

    Range("A2:C2").Merge
    Range("A2:C2").WrapText = True
    Range("A2:C2").Rows.AutoFit
End Sub
```

current working output:

[image]

need output:

[image]

Comment: @R . Saravana Kumar is necessary to merge cells?

Comment: Sub test1()
    Range("A2:C2").Merge
    Range("A2:C2").WrapText = True
   
    Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Value = "Process inform HMI finish oil fiber display not show we check found HMI damage after we check no have spare after we move HMI alarm display at control spinning to install. But the type of HMI not same. To convert graphic display.After transfer to HMI and test operation finished. Test system with process is working normal."
   
    Range("A2:C2").Rows.AutoFit
 End Sub

Answer (score 1):

You can check the below code for the auto fitting merged cells.

The cell width for column A to C is set to 12 each and for the height the ration that is 45%  of text length depends upon this width, if you want to change the width, you have to change the ratio as well.

```
Sub test1()


    Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Value = " Testing Testing TestingTestingTesting Testing Testing TestingTestingTesting Testing TestingTesting Testing Testing TestingTesting Testing Testing Testing TestingTesting Testing TestingTesting Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing Testing TestingTestingTesting Testing"
    Range("A2:C2").Merge
    Range("A2:C2").WrapText = True

    Columns("A:C").ColumnWidth = 12

    text_length = Len(Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Value)
    Rows("2:2").RowHeight = text_length * 0.45


End Sub
```

Comment: 409 height a bow height 1004 error how can throw expedition candling

Comment: ye multiplayer  in 0.45

Comment: Paste you function here and i shall check

Comment: dynamic data is fill in this data your code not working
Ex: two line only you put now not working

Comment: remember that row height has a limit. It can only be less than 410. you have to increase the cell width in order to fit the text in it.

Answer (score 0):

Change Sheet name and range and try the below code (Code will NOT merger BUT Wrap & Auto Fit. You can not auto fit columns or rows which are merge regarding this article https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/212010/you-cannot-use-the-autofit-feature-for-rows-or-columns-that-contain-me).

```
    Sub Test()
    '
        With Sheet2.Range("A1")
            .Value = "Process inform HMI finish oil fiber display not show we check found HMI damage after we check no have spare after we move HMI alarm display at control spinning to install. But the type of HMI not same. To convert graphic display.After transfer to HMI and test operation finished. Test system with process is working normal."
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
            .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
            .WrapText = True
        End With
        Sheet2.Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End Sub
```

Comment: I need in merger  cell

Comment: If you must merger then you have to increase column width instead of auto fit.